# Ionic2 forcetk issue with CORS

Tags: mobile, hybrid, forcetk, cors

following @ccoenraets' tutorial at http://coenraets.org/blog/2016/02/angular2-ionic2-salesforce/ I get an error with the CORS proxy (I think).

[image]

Is it possible to deploy my own CORS app in heroku?
Can I clone the code from somewhere?

When I build the app for android I also get a rather non descriptive message

Two different tries:

```
D:\Projects\ionic2-realty [master +3 ~4 -1 !]> ionic run android

? Compiling Sass to CSS
V Matching patterns: app/theme/app.+(ios|md).scss

? Copying fonts
V Matching patterns: node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)

? Copying HTML
V Matching patterns: app/**/*.html

? Compiling and bundling with Webpack...
V Using your webpack.config.js file
V Sass compilation complete
V HTML copied to www/build
V Compiling files complete.

Hash: b45dc76743816e7c7788
Version: webpack 1.12.11
Time: 5416ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.bundle.js  2.75 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built]
    + 369 hidden modules

V Webpack complete

V Fonts copied to www/build/fonts
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrib' of null
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
D:\Projects\ionic2-realty [master +3 ~5 -1 !]> ionic build android

? Compiling Sass to CSS
V Matching patterns: app/theme/app.+(ios|md).scss

? Copying fonts
V Matching patterns: node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)

? Copying HTML
V Matching patterns: app/**/*.html

? Compiling and bundling with Webpack...
V Using your webpack.config.js file
V Sass compilation complete
V HTML copied to www/build
V Compiling files complete.

Hash: b45dc76743816e7c7788
Version: webpack 1.12.11
Time: 6334ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.bundle.js  2.75 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built]
    + 369 hidden modules

V Webpack complete

V Fonts copied to www/build/fonts
Error: Cannot read property 'attrib' of null
D:\Projects\ionic2-realty [master +3 ~5 -1 !]>
```

Any help or ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to find the CORS proxy implementation in php from the original library implementation at https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/proxy.php and this repo facilitates the deployment to Heroku https://github.com/joshbirk/forcetkphpdemo 
I will give it a try and post my results